# Merge [schematic] and [schematics] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

When posting my first question, I noticed the [schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematics) (plural) and [schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematic) (singular) tags both exist. I propose setting [schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematic) to be a synonym of [schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematics).

- [1356 questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematics) have only [schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematics)
- [45 questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematic) have only [schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematic)
- [2 questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematic+schematics) have both tags

Concerning singular/plural; I cannot find a Stack Exchange consensus on which is best. Sometimes both are required, e.g. [window](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window) and [windows](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) are very completely different things and should remain different tags. On Electrical Engineering specifically, I found the same lack of consensus with plural synonyms winning in some cases like [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) and [resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resistors), but singular synonyms winning in cases like [connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connector) and [timer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timer).

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/batteries/synonyms
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/resistors/synonyms
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/connector/synonyms
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/timer/synonyms

Comment: Side remark: as a non-native English speaker, I never remember, but it seems we always use the plural form, or is that wrong? If you speak about a single device, do you say *"Please find the device schematics."* or *"Please find the device schematic here."*? Or *"Please find the schematic(s?) of the device here."* Which one is correct? Thanks!

Comment: @Basj - I would go for "Please find the [device's] schematics here". Pluralising `schematic` isn't essential, but if you are referring to the device, it should be the possessive `device's`. This is my opinion, there may be a real grammatical rule to follow! :)

Comment: Thanks @awjlogan! About singular/plural, in your example, why did you use plural in *"Please find the device's schematics here"*, since it is just one single device? Does this mean we nearly always use plural for schematics?

Comment: @Basj - there are likely to be multiple schematics for a single device. Maybe it's colloquial, but I would usually says `here are the schematics` even if it is just one page. I apologise for the lack of formal grammar!

Comment: @Basj @awjlogan I am a native American English speaker and at my work, we refer to `panel schematics` and `field schematics`. No possessive and no singular. I think grammar rules allow either way depending on what exactly you're trying to communicate. I suggested the plural tag because of tags like [circuits] and [resistors], and [units], but it appears plenty of singular tags exist as well like [connector], [led], and [pcb]

Comment: I'd tend to prefer schematics, even though there may be edge cases where the singular might be preferred. That seems to be confirmed by their existing relative frequency of usage on the site. Delete schematic, keep schematics.

Comment: I don't believe there's any benefit in merging the tags. [tag:schematic] should simply by removed - 45 questions isn't a lot. Unless there's a ease of moderation benefit in merging tags first and then remove one alias - someone who knows the mod tools better than me will have to make that call.

Comment: @Lundin, please see my edits to the question. I cannot find Stack Exchange consensus on whether singular/plural is preferred, and I see plenty of singular/plural tags which have been marked as synonyms.

Comment: @MicahLindstrom Stack Exchange consensus is irrelevant. What matters for terms on this site is 1) Is there a formal term derived from science or standardization? If so use that. 2) If not, then is there a "de facto" standard term used by EE? If so use that. 3) If not, then is there an engineering jargon term for it? If so use that. 4) If all of the previous failed, then yeah I suppose go look for SE tag naming policies.

Comment: In this case I believe _schematics_ (plural) is somewhere between 2 and 3.

Comment: Gonna weigh in on the schematic vs schematics usage. For "the device's (singular) schematic(s)" the correct version is "device's schematic" since device is a singular noun. If you take "schematic" to mean diagram then technically you can refer to all pages, each containing a diagram, as parts of one large diagram (schematic) which is the device. The difference between referring to schematic and schematics is whether you are referring to the whole or the parts. It's the difference between saying "the car" and "the car's parts."

Answer (score 7):

I say we use only the schematics tag since that is what every one types in anyway (and that is really the use of the tag). If I get 10 upvotes on this post I'll merge them.

Comment: The question and answer have only upvotes nearly one year later.  Everyone who has voted is in agreement with a change.  Considering the lack of traffic here on meta, I'd say 10 upvotes is arbitrarily high.  Please make the change; I saw a new question posted today with both tags, and I was confused as to what the difference was between the tags.

Comment: The question has over 10 upvotes, please act...